# Get argument type of lambda with auto specifier

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, generic-lambda

I have a meta function which gives me the type of the `I`-th argument of a lambda/function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

namespace details
{
    //! Spezialization for Funktion-Pointers
    template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
    std::tuple<Args...> getArgs(Ret (*)(Args...));

    //! Spezialization for Functor/Lambdas
    template<typename F, typename Ret, typename... Args>
    std::tuple<Args...> getArgs(Ret (F::*)(Args...));

    //! Spezialization for Functor/Lambdas
    template<typename F, typename Ret, typename... Args>
    std::tuple<Args...> getArgs(Ret (F::*)(Args...) const);

}; // namespace details

template<typename F, std::size_t I>
using GetArg = std::tuple_element_t<I, decltype(details::getArgs(std::declval<F>()))>;

int main()
{
    auto f1 = [](int a, int b){};
    static_assert(std::is_same<GetArg<decltype(f1), 0>, int>{}, "Not the same!");

    // auto f2 = [](int a, auto b){};
    // static_assert(std::is_same<GetArg<decltype(f2), 0>, int>{}, "Not the same!");
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8cca53c2078465c)

The second lambda with `auto` specifier does not compile as my spezializations are not matched, because `auto` is like a template parameter `T`, which is not known.
Is there a way of making this work for `f2` as well?

Since the lambda is an opaque type and a template function has no type unless instantiated with template argument types, I have not really any idea of how to make this work? Is it impossible?

Comment: Lambda with auto results into a class with a template operator(), so it gives infinite number of possible functions. Which result would you expect for auto argument?

Comment: I think it should be (partially) possible with something like [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get), but for `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss this:

```cpp
template <typename F>
decltype(getArgs(&F::operator())) getArgs(F);
```

So final version would be:

```cpp
namespace details
{
//! Spezialization for Funktion-Pointers
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> getArgs(Ret (*)(Args...));

//! Spezialization for Functor/Lambdas
template <typename F, typename Ret, typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> getArgs(Ret (F::*)(Args...));

//! Spezialization for Functor/Lambdas
template <typename F, typename Ret, typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> getArgs(Ret (F::*)(Args...) const);

template <typename F>
decltype(getArgs(&F::operator())) getArgs(F);

}; // namespace details

template <typename F, std::size_t I>
using GetArg = std::tuple_element_t<I, decltype(details::getArgs(std::declval<F>()))>;
```

Now it compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/r1PsE36Wx

Comment: Nice spezialization!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of making this work for `f2` as well?

No, as far I know.

You can see a generic lambda (a lambda with one or more `auto` arguments) almost as a template function (wrapped in a class).

Excluding the class wrapping, you can see

```
[](int a, auto b){};
```

almost as

```
template <typename T>
void foo (int a, T b)
 { };
```

You can't deduce the type of `b` from the lambda exactly as you can't deduce the type of `b` from `foo()`: it's decided calling the function (deducing the type form the argument) or explicating it (something as `foo<int>`).

But if you simply write `decltype(foo)`, the compiler can't decide which type is `T` so gives an error.

Anyway, I get an error also compiling

```
static_assert(std::is_same<GetArg<decltype(f1), 0>, int>{}, "Not the same!");
```

I suppose you have to write `GetArg` as follows

```
using GetArg = std::tuple_element_t<I, decltype(details::getArgs(&F::operator()))>;
// ..............................................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can maintain your actual `GetArg` but calling it with `+f1`

```
static_assert(std::is_same<GetArg<decltype(+f1), 0>, int>{}, "Not the same!");
// ........................................^^^
```

that is: converting the lambda to a function pointer.